# Error while inheriting web.assets_backend

Tags: css, xml, odoo

When inheriting `web.assets_backend` in **xml** file im getting the following getting error in Odoo12:

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 4:                 ON CONFLICT (module, name)
                    ^
" while parsing None:4, near
<data inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="/skit_freeze_header/static/src/css/freeze_header.css"/>
    </xpath>
</data>
```

Below is the code used:

```
<template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
```

Comment: what version of Odoo are you using?

Comment: Odoo-12 version

Answer (score 0):

Resolved..For Odoo12, postgres version is to satisfy 9.5 and above.(I was using 9.3)
I updated and tried. Setup gets completed and, while creating db ,"sassc" error occurs.
For resolving try the below commands:
1. pip install libsass
2. npm install--save-dev gulp-sass